# Stopping Android service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I wrote a program *for downloading an image from web using* `AsyncTask` in `service`. The downloading process works normally. I am using a `notification` for indicating the download progress, I also have *two buttons for start downloading and stop downloading*. 
But when I click the stop button the ongoing download can't stop. The notification manager continue the same.

**Main activity:**

```
public class ServicedownloadActivity extends Activity implements
        OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ServicedownloadActivity.this,
                    Myclass.class);
            startService(intent);

        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ServicedownloadActivity.this,
                    Myclass.class);
            stopService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Class contains serivce and asynchTask**

```
public class Myclass extends Service {

    URLConnection connection;
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public int getRandomNumber() {
        return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("df", "From oncreate");
        Toast.makeText(this, "on create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String responseTextt;
        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        Notification notification;
        CharSequence contentText;
        Context context;
        CharSequence contentTitle;
        PendingIntent contentIntent;
        int HELLO_ID = 1;
        long time;
        int icon;
        CharSequence tickerText;

        public void downloadNotification() {
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
            icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            tickerText = "Downloading...";
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, time);
            context = getApplicationContext();
            contentTitle = "Your download is in progress";
            contentText = "0% complete";
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            notificationIntent.setType("audio/*");
            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle,
                    contentText, contentIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {

                Log.d("trys:", "try");
                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://www.zapiture.com/resources/IMG_6812.JPG");
                connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url
                        .openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/img23.jpg");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                int previousProgress = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    if ((int) (total * 100 / fileLength) > previousProgress) {
                        previousProgress = (int) (total * 100 / fileLength);
                        publishProgress(""
                                + (int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            downloadNotification();

            super.onPreExecute();
            ;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

            contentText = Integer.parseInt(progress[0]) + "% complete";
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle,
                    contentText, contentIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Log.d("sf", "On Start");
        Toast.makeText(this, "on start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();

        task.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopSelf();
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("df", "From on Destroy");
        Toast.makeText(this, "on destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eldo,Welcome to StackOverflow, Please try this things before posting your code in Question 1) remove all commented lines 2) if you using eclipse select your code press `ctrl+shift+f` to format the code allignment ; to make your question represent the problem nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you that Make a `Boolean` flag variable initially `true` and while in `onDestroy()` change it to `false`

Now in `doInBackground` check the variable status if true then continue your task if false then stop it and just call `return;`

As the `AsyncTask` run in their separate `process` so evenif the Activity/Service got destroyed they keep executting.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using `AsyncTask` in a service, it's for using in an activity. If you need a service that automatically starts a worker thread, use `IntentService`. It will also automatically stop itself when done. Sending progress updates might require some more work, but it will be much cleaner than an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: +1 Even i recommend using IntentService rather than creating AsyncTask in Service

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `AsyncTask` to download, you can try to cancel the AsyncTask itself by [`cancel(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29),

```
task.cancel(true);
```

Comment: Its found and mentioned also the cancel just put the task as requested to cancel but it doesn't mean that task will surely 100% will get stopped and canceled,AFAIK, may be I am wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

Always remember the AsyncTask won't stop if its in middle of some processing even if you call stopService.Unless you call task's cancel method in service's onDestroy's implementation, it will be ended only once completed

So make following modification in code.

You basically need to add this.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    task.canel();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Also you are creating `DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();` inside on start so you cannot call task.cancel in onDestroy.Rather define `DownloadWebPageTask task;`
outside so `task.cancel` will be aviliable in `onDestroy`.